# Columns misaligned on DataTable; R pkg:DT

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have this code on R, using the `DT` package:

```
datatable( 
  data = relacao_das_turmas_365d %>%
    select(Turma = Turma_C, 
           Status,
           Farol,
           `Data de início`,
           `Nº de dias`,
           Coordenador, 
           `Alunos confirmados`,
           `Alunos Inscritos`,
           `Alunos Potenciais`,
           `Meta Alunos`,
           `% Meta de alunos`,
           Leads,
           `Investimento (Facebook)`,
           Faturamento, 
           ROI,
           `Ticket Médio`,
           `Taxa de conversão turma`,
           Local),

  extensions = 'Buttons',
  filter = 'top', 
  rownames = F, 

  options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                 scrollY = TRUE,
                 pageLength = 15,                
                 searchHighlight = TRUE, 
                 initComplete = JS(
                   "function(settings, json) {",
                   "$(this.api().table().body()).css({'font-size': '68%'});",
                   "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '68%'});",
                   "}"),

                 columnDefs = list(#list(width = '8px', targets = c(1:3)),
                                 list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 1:5),
                                 list(className = 'dt-left', targets = 6),
                                 list(className = 'dt-right', targets = 7:16),
                                 list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 17)),
                 dom = 'fBrtip',
                 buttons = list(
                              list(extend = 'colvis', columns = c(1:17)),
                              c('excel'))


                 )
) %>%

  formatCurrency(c('Investimento (Facebook)', 'Faturamento', 'ROI', 'Ticket Médio'), 'R$ ') %>%
  formatPercentage(c('Taxa de conversão turma','% Meta de alunos') , 2) %>%
  formatStyle(
    'Status',
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('Péssimo', 'Ruim', 'Bom', 'Excelente'), 
                                 c('#2E2E2E', '#FA5858', '#F4FA58', '#01C46B')),
    color = styleEqual(c('Péssimo', 'Ruim', 'Bom', 'Excelente'), 
                       c('white', 'white', '#2E2E2E', '#2E2E2E'))
  )
```

The output shoud be a table with 15 rows, horizontal scrolling and pagination. But the headers are misaligned like this:

[The misaligned headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQYBe.png)

And if I click on `Nº de dias` to sort by `asc` values, it fixes the problem. See on picture below:

[correct header alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su7k5.png)

There's a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @42- can u help me?

Comment: Hi, I have same issue. Did u find a fix?

Comment: Hi @ktyagi, unfortunately not.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas, if it helps, what I have found is that its special options like search highlight or fixed first n columns, that cause issues. If you make a simple table its ok!